# Red vid open window with maximize

Tags: red

When run this code, it will open the window with a default size:

```
View [
    text "window open with default size"
]
```

If a give a size explicitly, it will open a window with that size:

```
View [
    size 400x400
    text "window open with fixed size"
]
```

But how do I open a window with the maximum size / maximized?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what kinda works for now on at least *Microsoft* Windows

```
offset: 0x60
max-size: system/view/screens/1/size - offset
view [
    size max-size
    text "window open with max screen size"
]
```

But, this is because of the way it's currently handled, as you can see, most window handling features aren't currently implemented:

[image]

(based on chat):